# difference between number and generic parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am writing a class in typescript and don't know how to differentiate between generic and number type parameter. Code example

```
class Test<T> {
  remove(value: T): boolean;
  remove(index: number): boolean;
  remove(indexOrValue: T|number): boolean {
    if (typeof indexOrValue === "number") {
      /* What about new Test<number>() */
      const index = indexOrValue as number;
      this.items.splice(index, 1)
      return true;
    } else {
      const index = this.items.indexOf(indexOrValue as T)
      if (index > -1) this.items.splice(index, 1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

**PS**: I don't know this problem specifically that y i am writing here instead of searching

Comment: the only way to solve this is to have two different methods for the different operations, e.g. `remove(T)` and `removeAt(number)`. As an additional benefit, this makes the code more readable and you don't need any runtime decisions.

Comment: I know this. But I am writing base class which is already used in many other classes. thats y i have to implement same methods.

Comment: If you have a field in the class of type T then you can check its type on top of the argument type. It's a hack, but it'd work. Of course you can't distinguish the *intention* of the caller. Without any external information there's no way to do this since for `T=number` the signatures are equivalent and therefore indistinguishable.

Comment: if `T` is `number`, then when someone calls this function how do know if they want to remove by value or by index?

Comment: @IngoBürk even then, you can only remove elements and no longer by index.

Comment: Well yeah, obviously. I would hope this is clear to OP.

Comment: I second @ccarton. This base class has design flaws. You don't know the intention of the user, if you can't tell then the API design is wrong.

Comment: @ccarton this is exactly my question as well, i have limitation here because many classes are already using this class. and i don't want to rewrite all of them. that is y i asked this question.

Comment: @a1300 This class is basically for developers. we know the intention of user. basically its rewrite of one java class. Java can do it but in typescript i don't know how to do this.

Comment: @9me you can't do this in Typescript. Typescript is a compile-time only feature. When you execute the code, JavaScript can't tell if its a number or generic parameter

Comment: @9me Are you saying you have existing Typescript / Javascript classes that have various function signatures but the same function name? That should not be possible. Javascript won't be able to handle this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with separate method route as well, but if you are looking for a solution with exact requirements, I think I have found what you are looking for by checking type of an item in array.

Take a look at the code:

```
class Test<T> {
    items: T[] = [];

    remove(value: T): boolean;
    remove(index: number): boolean;
    remove(indexOrValue: T|number): boolean {
        const length = this.items.length;
        if (length === 0) {
            return false;
        }
         
        const isArgumentNumber = typeof indexOrValue === "number";
        const isGenericTypeNumber = typeof this.items[0] === 'number';
        if (isArgumentNumber) {
            if (isGenericTypeNumber) {
                // TODO: When input and class both are number
            } else {
                // TODO: When input is number but class is not   
            }
        } else {
            // TODO: When input is not a number
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: But if i have `genNumber.items.push(1);` and i will do `genNumber.remove(1);` then it will remove the wrong value.

Comment: @9me that is what I assumed you would want to do. What I have provided is a way to identify if type of generic item is number or not. How you use it, it's upto you code is just for demonstration purpose.

Comment: What example code displays is way to identify type and no other logic as question is related to identification of generic type and not related to functionality of the method.

Comment: I am looking for something like java class. Because I know in java you can define two different methods with number and with `Object` type methods. I wanted to know if same thing exists in TS too

Comment: @9me you could with code I provide. Now how you want to use it its up to you. You can modify if condition according to your implementation.

Comment: See your own example `genNumber.remove(1); // will not remove anything as 1 doesn't exist in array` here 1 is index and it should remove item 6.

Comment: Ah I see what  you mean, but that is my whole point the code is for demonstration purpose only. I do not have java classes to see what actual implementation is but you do. Only thing mentioned in your question is find a way to determine type of generic but not any information regarding what method should do in each case where type is number and input is number and vise-a-versa.

Comment: @9me anyways, I have updated my code with TODOs fee free to replace it wit YOUR OWN implementation and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

In order to solve this problem instead defining many functions or constructors (like some programming languages like `c++`), just define one function or constructor and use `switch-case` or `if-else` to handle it. maybe for two different type you want to implement two different functions, but it is so easy to manage, just create two function for each usage, and then call them from your `remove()` function in `switch-case` or `if-else`.

Comment: Question is how you can differentiate between generic and number type, because if user used number as generic type, then both cases are same for compiler but not for me. take a look on my example.